# Qwt widget showed in QT creator, but when compile error cannot open include file

Tags: qt-creator, qwt

I compile qwt as instruction in INSTALL file for qt creator using `MSVC`, after adding `CONFIG +=qwt`, I got the widget showed on qt creator, I try to include some header file, but when I compile, I got error

> "can open include file, no such file or directory"

what I've done was:

- I didn't make any change in ***pri** files
- I use QT 5.0 commamd prompt to the downloaded qwt pack and type `qmake qwt.pro`
  then I open Visual studio 2010 command prompt (that I got after installing visual studio 2010 EXPRESS) and type `nmake` , `nmake install`.
- then back in to directory of QT 5.0 command prompt I type `qmake -set QMAKEFEATURES = C:\qwt-6.0.1-rc3\features`

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the commands used for compilation ( the output you see in the creator ) of your application and check the include paths if there is something Qwt related ( CONFIG -= silent ).

I would guess you won't see anything because it has to be:
"qmake -set QMAKEFEATURES C:\qwt-6.0.1-rc3\features".

The "=" is wrong.

PS: for Qwt related question better ask on the Qwt support channels

Comment: Thank yo so much Uwe, although I reinstall and remove the "=" sign, it was still not recognized, but taken from your hint, I looked into the output file and realized that for some reasons, qmake tried to look for the lib and include folder under the parent folder name qwt-6.1.0 instead of qwt-6.0.1-rc3 although i didn't change anything in configue.pri file, I change the name of this parent folder and everything works :)